# Exported excel from ag-grid has incorrect formatting

Tags: ag-grid

I am facing an issue in ag-grid. I have created a plnkr to reproduce the issue.

In following plunkr, first column's cells are displayed green but when we download in excel they shows blue.
This is because of one cell having both classes, blue and green.
Please note the cellClass function provided to Age column def.

```
            {
                headerName: 'Age', field: 'age', width: 90,

                cellClass:function(params){

                    if(params.data.age === 23){
                      return ['blueBackground', 'greenBackground'];
                    }
                    return '';
                }
            }
```

But the question is, why does this affect the other column cells in exported excel?

I could understand, if only that particular cell, having both conflicting classes would have the problem of showing either one color.

Plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/OdIwGznvmTYwkUTKZOEa?p=preview